# Как выложить изображение?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Создал новый `spring-boot` проект, пытаюсь сделать дефолтный контроллер чтобы возвращал изображение, т.е. в `localhost:8080` открывалась картинка. Пробовал возвращать `bufferedimage` - в браузере код. Как реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выложите код из скриншота текстом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возвращать надо массив байт и указать в хидере, что это картинка, например:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity index() throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(
            MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/pictures/image.png"));

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);

    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
        .body(baos.toByteArray());
}
```