# Как хранить фото для товара в БД?

Tags: java, postgresql, изображения, hibernate, spring-mvc

Пишу интернет-магазин `MVC Rest api` с использованием `Spring Boot`, `Hibernate`, `PostgreSQL`. Мне необходимо иметь для товаров фотографии. Соответственно, отсюда вопрос как вообще это реализовать? Вариант с хранением картинок прямо в БД не подойдет, поэтому я решил хранить в *БД* ссылки на фото, которые у меня хранятся на жестком диске. Но как все это реализовать в коде? В `Entity` получается у меня поле с типом `String`?

Java:

```java
private String image;
```

SQL:

```sql
alter table drink add column image varchar;
```

А в БД столбец с ссылками (путь) к фото? В таком случае как вывести изображение на стороне клиента, ведь мне будет выдаваться не фото, а ссылка? Получается нужно писать некий метод, который будет до вывода находить файл по ссылке и выводить его? Но как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>*Рекомендую третий вариант - он проще.*</sub>

---

1. Можно хранить файлы в базе в формате [Base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), тоже строка будет, только очень длинная. Размер такой строки в байтах будет больше, чем размер самой картинки. Для доступа к таким картинкам надо будет `endpoint` писать:

   ```java
   @GetMapping(value = "/base64/red-dot")
   public ResponseEntity<String> getPicture() {
       // получаем строку base64 из базы
       String base64 = getImagePng("red-dot");

       return ResponseEntity.ok(base64);
   }
   ```

   Строка, которая должна храниться в базе (т. е. картинка в формате `Base64`) должна выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
   data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
   AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
   9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
   ```

   На клиенте получаем картинку с помощью [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

   ```html
   <img id="red-dot" alt="Red dot">
   <script>
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('GET', '/base64/red-dot');
       xhr.onload = function() {
           var img = document.getElementById("red-dot");
           img.src = xhr.responseText;
       };
       xhr.send();
   </script>
   ```

   См: [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/11141611)

   ---
2. Если хранить файлы в папке на диске - тоже нужен будет `endpoint` для доступа к ним. На сервере: получаем путь к файлу из БД, зачитываем файл по полученному пути и возвращаем массив байт:

   См: [Как выложить изображение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1111344/328896)

   На клиенте:

   ```html
   <img src="/endpoint/image" alt="image">
   ```

   ---
3. Можно добавить эти файлы в ресурсы проекта, в папку `src/main/webapp`, и загружать вместе с веб приложением. На клиенте путь к картинке (относительно этой папки) будет выглядеть примерно так:

   ```html
   <img src="/pictures/image.png" alt="image">
   ```